# ¿MVUE and pivotal quantity for a random variable with $2x/\theta^2$ density?

Tags: statistics

For an independent identically distributed sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, I need help to find the Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator and the pivotal quantity (for the confidence interval) to estimate the $\theta$ parameter of a random variable with $2x/\theta^2$ density function with $0<x<\theta$. Thank you.

Edit: I've found a sufficient and complete estimator for $\theta$ is the sample's maximum.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you're asking. That's probably the reason for the down-votes and the votes to close.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation but, as you can see, english is not my first language.

Comment: Your last sentence mentions a sample. In many problems one considers an independent identically distributed sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, sorry for omitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abbreviate $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ by $\max$.

Then
\begin{align}
\Pr(\max<x) & = \Pr(X_1<x\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n<x) = \left(\Pr(X_1<x)\right)^n \\[8pt]
& = \left(\frac 1 {\theta^2} \int_0^x 2u\,du\right)^n = \frac{x^{2n}}{\theta^{2n}},
\end{align}
so
$$
f_\max(x) = \frac{2nx^{2n-1}}{\theta^{2n}}\text{ for }0<x<\theta.
$$
Consequently
$$
\operatorname{E}(\max) = \int_0^\theta u f_\max(u)\,du= \frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}} \int_0^\theta u^{2n}\,du = \frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\theta^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \frac{2n}{2n+1}\theta.
$$
Consequently $\dfrac{2n+1}{2n}\cdot\max$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.  You've shown that $\max$ is both sufficient and complete, so now you can apply the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem to this unbiased estimator.